# Is it possible to add custom properties to a .csproj file use by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm developing a creation tool that will be compiling media objects as well as C# code into a certain format

This tool will be compiling C# code directed by a standard Visual Studio csproj file. Ideally i would like to store non C# project related information alongside the information about that code structure and compile instructions, such as media locations and compile information. This extra information/content will not be built with MSBuild.

My optimum way to do this would be to store all of the compile and structure information into one project file for example a csproj file. My initial investigation into doing this lead to Visual studio complaining about unrecognized tags when loading the project.

My main question is: **Is there a way for me to store extra non-MSBuild related data inside a csproj file without Visual Studio or MSBuild complaining about unrecognized XML tags.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can extend the information inside the csproj files with custom tags/properties.

See this: [Adding custom information to CSPROJ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992511/csproj-extension)